# Get cms page in template file does'nt work after edit cms page Magento 1.9

Tags: cms, cms-pages

I have loaded a cms page in a template file. But after an edit to the cms page, I get an white page instead of this cms page.
I am using the following line to get the cms page.

```
echo $this->helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter(Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($this->getPrivacyCmsPageIdentifier())->getContent());
```

Comment: Probably when you saved the cms page, you saved it for specific store and you are trying to get the page in another store view.

Comment: Nope, I use the cms page that is just for the Dutch storeview. At the dutch storeview I get also a white page.

Comment: are you sure the page is correct? Can you view the page as "a page" in the browser?

Comment: @Marius yes, that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$pageIdentifier = 'your_page_identifier';
$pageContent = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageIdentifier, 'identifier')->getContent();
```